# NullReferenceException adding to list within array

Tags: c#, arrays, nullreferenceexception

Ok, im trying to make something but it isnt working out for me as well as i thought it would.
Bassicly im trying to Add to a list within an custom class array, is this makes any sense.
Here is some code to perhaps make it easier to understand:

```
public class pfft
{
    public class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int br { get; set; }
    }
    public class team
    {
        public int totalbr { get; set; }
        public List<Player> players { get; set; }
    }
}
public pfft.team[] Teams;
public int tmcount = 4;
private void btn_team_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Teams = new pfft.team[tmcount]();
    foreach(pfft.Player p in getallplayers())
    {
        Teams[0].players.Add(p);
    }
}
```

This is bassicly all im doing, but when trying to add the player to the players list it crashes. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
The p it is trying to add does contain values, I checked that in the debugger
I have also tried calling

```
Teams[0].players = new List<pfft.Player>();
```

but when i try that it will give the Nullexception at that part...

Comment: You haven't initialized the array itself with any entries. You must assign a sized array to 'Teams' before addressing it with an index

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. Creation of array do not create its objects:

   [image]

   so you need to iterate through array and create those objects:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < tmcount; ++i)
        Teams[i] = new pfft.team();
   ```
2. You are not initializing `public List<Player> players { get; set; }` after `Teams = new pfft.team[tmcount]();`:

   ```
   Teams = new pfft.team[tmcount]();
   foreach(pfft.Player p in getallplayers())
   {
       Teams[0].players = new List<pfft.Player>();
       Teams[0].players.Add(p);
   }
   ```
3. To not have to initialize players in each team, use a slightly different property:

   ```
   public class Team
   {
       private List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

       public int totalbr { get; set; }
       public List<Player> Players 
       {
           get { return players; }
           set { players = value; }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I did try so.. when i do that i get this: http://puu.sh/5y6tg.png
Or better: http://puu.sh/5y6z2.png, And im not sure what you mean with the first problem.

Comment: Ahhhhh i see.. i was looking in the right direction.. just didn't realise i needed to make a 'new team' beside the list of players.
Thank you very much!

Comment: The initialization of `players` needs to occur before the `foreach` loop, not inside it.

Comment: It should but OP is using only Teams[0] here.

Comment: @280Z28 That is indeed what i was initially doing.. but while trying to figure out what was going wrong i changed a lot to try stuff out..